# How to skip error checking at Rmarkdown compiling?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was writing an Rmarkdown document (compile to HTML) in RStudio, and there are some code chunks that deliberately generate errors. for example:

````
```{r}
sum(a)
```
````

Since there is no previous definition for `a` this chunk will naturally generate an error message like `object 'a' not found`. I'd like this error message displayed in the final HTML file, but when I press `Ctrl+Shift+K` in RStudio to "Knit HTML", the compiler reported the error and stopped knitting.

So how can I tell `knitr` to ignore such error at compiling time and display it in the knitted HTML document?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `error=TRUE` to continue in case of errors: from [the description of knitr chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options),

> error: (TRUE; logical) whether to preserve errors (from stop()); by default, the evaluation will not stop even in case of errors!! if we want R to stop on errors, we need to set this option to FALSE

`rmarkdown::render`, the function behind RStudio's "Knit HTML" button/Ctrl-Shift-K shortcut, sets `error=FALSE` by default (in contrast to `knitr::knit`, which defaults to `error=TRUE`)

````
```{r error=TRUE}
sum(a)
```
````

Comment: Thanks Ben! I was reading the r markdown reference guide pdf instead of the knitr website, and I guess its description of `error` needs to be updated. The similar wording in the pdf file makes me think that the behaviour of `error` option is just like that of `message` and `warning`.

Comment: I added this to the top of my RStudio script: `#+ setup, error=TRUE`

Comment: I can never remember if I need `error=TRUE` or `FALSE`. ChatGPT suggested to think of `error=TRUE` as  "errors are okay" or **"it's `TRUE` that we can have errors"**.  Lets see if that sticks...