# Errors in R markdown document after knitting

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have a markdown file that I have just finished knitting. The file is discussing what I have done in my R project for a data analytics course. I am receiving so many error messages after the knit within my report however this code all worked before while I was working in r projects. for example here. the error appears at the end.

Cleaning and Filtering
Step 1: heartrate_data heartrate_data is a very large data set so I filter ‘heartrate_data’ to contain data for user_6 only

```
heartrate_data <- filter(heartrate_data, Id == "2022484408")
and then filter for date

heartrate_data <- heartrate_data %>% filter(grepl('4/12/2016', Time))
and then re label Id to user_6

heartrate_data[heartrate_data == "2022484408"] <- "user_6"
## Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

So, my question is if there is no actual error within this code do I need to go through and give attention to all these error messages showing up? I have many more within my markdown. The errors seem un related though because this is how I coded while in my R projects. Is there a way to refrain R knit from including these error messages? Thank you

Here are a few more examples.

```
view(sleep_datatwo)
## Error in view(sleep_datatwo): object 'sleep_datatwo' not found

sleep_datatwo <- aggregate(TotalHoursAsleep ~ User, sleep_data, mean)
## Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'User' not found

sleep_datatwo <- sleep_datatwo %>% 
  rename(
    avg_hours_asleep = TotalHoursAsleep)
## Error in rename(., avg_hours_asleep = TotalHoursAsleep): object 'sleep_datatwo' not found
```

sleep_datatwo is in my environment, object User is within my sleep_data data frame.

Thank you!

Comment: (1) `view` in an r-markdown document makes little sense to me, perhaps `glimpse` or `str` _maybe_, but ... not sure. (2) It doesn't matter what is in your global environment, R-markdown documents are run with a clean environment. Use `params:` in your document, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html.

Comment: So use parameterized reports to exclude these errors from the knit somehow? @r2evans

Comment: Use parameterized reports to pass data from the calling environment so that the rmarkdown document actually sees them.

Answer (score 2):

The extremely short answer is yes, you can prevent the errors from interfering with knitting like so:

````
```{r error=TRUE message=FALSE}
your code here
```
````

See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280043/how-to-skip-error-checking-at-rmarkdown-compiling) for more explanation, and more details on different chunk options can be found [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/). However, if you want to display the results of your code, it would probably be best if your code actually ran, right?

All of your errors are object not found errors. I think the problem you are having is that the RMarkdown document does not contain any of the data from your R project. It doesn't matter if the data is loaded in your R environment or in another file within the project. You need to load your data into the RMarkdown document specifically. You can either do this within a code block in the document:

````
```{r}
data <- read_csv("data.csv")
```
````

Or by using [params](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-use.html) as @r2evans suggested. In the header of the R Markdown file:

```
---
title: Your Title Here
output: html_document
params:
  data: data.csv
---
```

Also, just fyi, you need to do this with packages too. I recommend you load in all necessary packages and documents in one code block. If you don't want the code to display in the output:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE}
library("tidyverse")
library("car")
data <- read_csv("data.csv")
```
````

To test that everything is loaded correctly before knitting:

In RStudio - Press the broomstick button in the "Environment" tab to erase all environmental variables. Restart R under the "Session" dropdown menu to start a new clean session.

In base R - Just close R and reopen it to erase all environmental variables and previously loaded packages.

Make sure your RMarkdown file loads in all necessary packages and files, then try knitting again.

Comment: (1) `{r error=TRUE message=FALSE}` needs commas (and the last block is missing one, too); (2) `error=TRUE` is the default, that should change the errant behavior. Your points of loading the data or passing params is the key component here, well-explained.

Comment: Okay thank you. I understand the parameters better now. However, these errors can not be from this as I have code within the markdown that loads data..

"First I imported sleepDay_merged, weightLogInfo_merged, heartrate_seconds_merged, and hourlyIntensities data sets."

sleep_data <- read.csv("/cloud/project/capstone project/R Projects/sleepDay_merged.csv")
weightLog_data <- read.csv("/cloud/project/capstone project/R Projects/weightLogInfo_merged.csv")
heartrate_data <- read.csv("/cloud/project/capstone project/R Projects/heartrate_seconds_merged.csv")

Comment: I am not required to put these in parameters as they are part of code chunks correct?